# I am working on getting the abstractive summaries of the Inshorts dataset using Huggingface's pre-trained Pegasus model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, summarization

I am working on getting the abstractive summaries of the Inshorts dataset using Huggingface's pre-trained Pegasus model.

I am trying to use this model on ‘inshorts’ dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/shashichander009/inshorts-news-data/metadata) where I basically need a summary generated by the pretrained model for each sample of Inshorts to predict the summary using the input as ‘Shorts’ column in the dataset.
Hence I tried to iterate over the ‘Shorts’ column but throws an error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Here is the background code:

```
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer

tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")

model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")
```

Here is the code related to dataset:

```
import io

df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['inshorts.xlsx']))
```

Here is the code where it throws error:

```
for a in range(0,3):
  
text = df.iloc[a,1]
  
updated_text= ' """ ' + text + ' """ ' 
  
print(updated_text)
```

Error is in this line:

```
tokens = tokenizer(updated_text , truncation=True, padding="longest", return_tensors="pt")

summary = model.generate(**tokens)
  
tokenizer.decode(summary[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1) Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre]; *"Error is in this line*" followed by a 3-line snippet is not helpful or informative 2) Please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you here), and do not use unnecessary bold text

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `tokenizer` remains `None` after `tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/pegasus-xsum")` has run. There is a pre-requirement package named `SentencePiece` for running `pegasus`, probably you have installed, but keep in mind after installation you must `restart` your session/kernel for the changes taking effect. After the above steps, the tokenizer variable would hold `transformers.models.pegasus.tokenization_pegasus.PegasusTokenizer` object and it solves the issue.